# Why does a thermocouple have two outputs (V+ and V-)?

Tags: thermocouple

[image]

Does that mean that there is two different voltages?

The potential is used to determine the temperature. (?)

I understand it's the seebeck effect  dictates how the thermocouple works.

Apologies if I'm missing a simple concept.

I have had no experience with thermcouples prior to my current thermopile project.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, when you use the voltmeter, don't you always need to probe two points in the circuit? With only one probe connected to the thermocouple you wouldn't really read any volts measurements, since they are measurements of electric potential difference.

Comment: ALL voltage sources have at least two terminals. Voltage is ALWAYS specified relative to some reference value (often "ground").  The concept of a single terminal voltage source makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's effectively a voltage source, a bit like a battery (given fixed thermal conditions). So, of course, it has two terminals.

The potential between the two terminals, measured at the meter, is a nonlinear function of the temperatures at Th and the temperature at T0, so if you want the temperature at Th you must measure the temperature at T0 using some method other than a thermocouple (or, as they did in the days of yore, place the two junctions at T0 in an ice-water slurry to control the temperature at 0°C).

Very roughly, the voltage output is proportional to the temperature difference between Th and T0. To get a more accurate measurement you can calculate the thermocouple voltage equivalent to the temperature T0 if it was compared to a reference junction of, say 0°C, and then add that voltage to the measured voltage at the meter to get a new voltage, then find the temperature corresponding to that voltage with a 0°C reference junction (if T0 was 0°C rather than whatever it really is). If T0 happens to be 0°C (perhaps due to that ice-water bath)  the voltage will be 0uV.

Comment: if I recall rightly, you'll have about 40 microvolts per degree C difference, for the standard iron-constantan thermooouple. But that's between TWO wires.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf About 55uV/°C for type J (Iron-Constantan). Type K is more like 42uV/°C. Some of the high temperature thermocouples such as R and S have much less output, and B is downright nasty (the curve flattens out and inverts near room temperature).

Answer (score 1):

ALL voltage sources have at least two terminals.
Voltage is ALWAYS specified relative to some reference value (often "ground").
The concept of a single terminal voltage source makes no sense.

So, a thermocouple is a voltage source with an output voltage measured on one lead relative to the other lead.

Answer (score 0):

Really there is only one output, which is the voltage difference between the two terminals (V+, V-). The V- is used as the reference going into the multimeter/circuitry. On your diagram, Tv is simply V+ minus V-. In other terms, you don't measure the voltage referenced to ground, something you'd normally do for a power supply or amplifier output.

Yes the voltage difference is used to determine the relative temperature. Be warned that the voltage difference may be quite small (uV - mV range), so if you have a cheap multimeter you will likely need to amplify the voltage with an instrumentation amplifier.

Here is a quick reading:

https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/measuring-temp-using-thermocouples.html